# HAML, Add class to image_tag

Tags: haml

I have

```
= image_tag  "chart.jpg"
```

I am new to HAML so how do I add a class to this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Assuming this is rails (Haml doesn't have its own `image_tag` helper, but [Rails does](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag)), then the second argument is an options hash where you can specify the class:

```
=image_tag  "chart.jpg", :class => "my_class"
```

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I am a front end developer/designer so my knowledge is basic at best.  It is Rails.  What you had worked great. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Stumbled across this answer when I was looking for something else and thought I'd throw in a little update to use the more modern formatting :)

`=image_tag 'chart.jpg', class: 'my_class'`